# How to locate path of generated wsdl in Spring-ws

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

I have generated webservice using spring-ws. I have deployed my application in tomcat and deployed without any error. I am not able to find the path for WSDL. Please help me how to form path for wsdl.

My web.xml:

```
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>listener><servlet><servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class></servlet><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>sprig-ws</servlet-name><url-pattern>/</url-pattern></servlet-mapping> <context-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws--servlet.xml</param-value></context-param>
```

spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
      <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller"
    class="org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller">
</bean> 
 <bean id="loginEndpoint" class="com.cloudexult.endpoint.LoginEndpoint">
</bean>
 <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="loginmanager" portTypeName="LoginService" locationUri="/loginService/"
                  targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Login/definitions">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schema/Login.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

Answer (score 9):

Your wsdl should be accessible through:

```
http://<servername>:<port>/<context-path>/loginService.wsdl
```

Can you try this and tell us if it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried this URL and it worked http://<servername>:<port>/<context-path>/loginmanager.wsdl . The 'id' name specified in <sws:dynamic-wsdl> is the wsdl generated name.

Comment: what is the <context-path> in this example?i am also stuck at the same problem.

Comment: The <context-path> would be your web application's context path, e.g. if you call your webapp via http://myserver:8080/myapp, "myapp" would be the context path.

Comment: I see the servlet-mapping for ws calls is defined as <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> in your code. And the location-uri in spring-ws definition is defined as locationUri="/loginService/". Ideally both should have same value and then the wsdl can be accessed like this assuming /loginService is set in <url-pattern> in servlet mapping.. 

myserver:8080/loginService/loginService.wsdl

Answer (score 3):

If you are really stuck, enabling log4j to print spring debug logs will help you.
Enable debug logging of spring by following in `log4j.properties` :

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Once that is done, restart your container, look for following in the DEBUG log :

```
20:51:16,718 DEBUG main http.MessageDispatcherServlet:469 - Published [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition@61bf8785] as wsdl11Definition.wsdl
```

Above is just an example, however the last component of the log, will give you the URI of your WSDL.